# Database sum() values together if string matches in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access, criteria

Sorry for the basic question, I've spent the best part of a hour figuring this out and I'm at my limit. I'm trying to add all values together if a string matches a certain size, for context I'm adding wall tiles together for a client, here's an example table;

| Code | TileSize | TileQty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BG3215 | 8mm | 1 |
| BG3545 | 10mm | 3 |
| BG3246 | 8mm | 4 |
| BG3745 | 8mm | 1 |
| BG3255 | 12mm | 2 |

My VBA:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim eight As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQLeight As String
strSQLeight= "SELECT SUM(TileQty) FROM PickQuery WHERE TileSize = '8mm'"

Set eight= db.OpenRecordset(strSQLeight)
'Error line ^

sometextbox = eight.Fields(0).Value
```

Run-Time error:
Too few parameters expected 3

Intended result is to return 6 (6 x "8mm" strings)

I assume there should be another argument in there but after looking in stack overflow and on google for help, I can't see another way to write this.

Comment: is `dsum` easier for you?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dsum   Not 100%, but i think the parenthesis on `8mm` should be `"`

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but "I've spent the best part of a hour figuring this out and I'm at my limit": an hour isn't really that long when you're trying to solve a problem.

Comment: @HoneyBadger It is when its a simple SQL query, No need to get passive.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I will check that out and see If I can come up with a solution, Cheers

Comment: @Nathan_Sav That works great! Code looks cleaner too, thank you!

Comment: @Nathan_Sav How can you add another parameter? is it: DSum("CornerQty", "PickQuery", "TileQty = '8mm'" And "TileType = 'Plastic'")

Comment: put the entire last argument in double quotes: `DSum("CornerQty", "PickQuery", "TileQty = '8mm' And TileType = 'Plastic'")`

Comment: @topsail I owe you all a drink! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly for me (running in an MSAccess DB, vba module):

```
Sub foo()
    
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    Dim eight As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQLeight As String
    strSQLeight = "SELECT SUM(TileQty) FROM PickQuery WHERE TileSize = '8mm'"
    Set eight = db.OpenRecordset(strSQLeight)
    sometextbox = eight.Fields(0).Value

End Sub
```

Is there something we are missing? How are you running this code? Is it in an access vba module? Somewhere else?

Comment: I'm running this on form load, I'm populating a textbox with this value.

Comment: It is strange. It also works for me no problems at all in a form load event. What are you running with: Windows OS version ?, MSAccess Version # ? Any chance you can put this db somewhere on a file share for inspection - I'm very befuddled too.

Comment: For what it's worth, Nathan_Sav's idea also works:  `sometextbox = DSum("TileQty", "PickQuery", "TileSize = '8mm'")` (not answering the question or figuring out what's wrong, but at least working around the problem).

Answer (score 0):

> Too few parameters expected 3

This means, that your query `PickQuery` is missing three parameter values.

Most likely, these are values fetched from the form where you call this code.